# iOS / PhoneGap app fails to download remote images/video via REST API after 60secs - why is it timing out?

Tags: ios, xcode, rest, drupal, cordova

We have built an in-house Enterprise iPad2+ application that connects to a Drupal CMS, where content (text/images/video) is being delivered to the app via a REST API.

When the user launches the app for the first time, they are prompted to download the content over WIFI network. We are experiencing content failing to download inconsistently i.e. sometimes 60 images fail to download; other times 20 images fail. Since we've added video into the download mix, the content is failing even more often.

**Server details:**

- Windows server
- IIS7.5
- PHP 5.3
- MYSQL5.1

**App details:**

- **Require.js:** *provides JavaScript file and module loading*
- **Backbone.js:** *provides a frontend JavaScript application framework*
- **Cordova (v2.7.0):** *Used to provide an environment to run on iOS*
- **Raphael.js:** *For procedural graphics and animations*
- **jQuery and plugins:** *For Dom manipulation, animations and interactions*
- **Bootstrap:** *Base framework for HTML mark-up*

**Download process is as follows:**

1. User launches app and is prompted to download content
2. Download begins
3. The app now makes AJAX call to REST API to fetch content
4. Upon a successful fetch, the REST API delivers an array of content (text/images/video) - max video filesize 11mb
5. Content is delivered synchronously

We can add logic to keep retrying upon failure, but this could result in an indefinite loop. The content download size is approx. 50mb, over WIFI.

**Our testing:**

- We have tried from 3 different locations in the world: SA, UK and US and similar issues.
- We've tested a 300mb download from the same server, on the same iPad and it downloads fine

### **QUESTION:**

- Can anyone tell us why this would be failing?
- Could the problem be with a Drupal configuration issue we're missing?

---

### **UPDATE 25 August:**

We have done some more research and it seems the problem may be a result of iOS Safari timing out at 60secs, and then everything fails after that that to download - see here: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?111231-iOS-Safari-Mobile-AJAX-timeout

Has anyone else come across this issue?

We have tried downloading over LAN, and that is 100% fine. WIFI is the issue.

We have tried refreshing the download script after x seconds and resetting the timeout counter. We've tried to detect if a download has failed and to continue retrying it.

Stumped at this point...

---

---

### **UPDATED SOLUTION 28 August:**

**UPDATED SOLUTION:** we have fixed the problem. The issue fundamentally lies in the fact that iOS Safari times out at ***60secs***. Why? We have no idea... What we were doing was fetching the full list files to download, and then downloading them synchronously. What happened at 60secs, is the download times out and we were losing our file list. What we did to resolve this, is we saved the files not downloaded list at 60secs, then started the download process again with this new list, and repeated this process until all files successfully downloaded.

---

Comment: So, this is basically a website repackaged as an app?

Comment: Does the same Rest API fail on PC? If so, the issue has nothing to do with iPad.

Comment: This is not a website packaged as an app. It's a standalone native iPad app. Does not work on a web browser. When downloading via the Xcode Simulator it fails as well.

Comment: If I read it right, the logic is, hit the API and download everything at once. Is that right? What about hitting the API and getting a list of resources first, and then the client fetches one at a time. This will be slower, but will also let you resume if something goes wrong. IE, you can check to see if the resource was downloaded already first.

Comment: Thanks Raymond - Yes, we've tried doing exactly what you suggest. The problem is that it seems to time-out @60secs and then anything after that fails. Similar to what's happening here: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?111231-iOS-Safari-Mobile-AJAX-timeout - and there seems to be no way to refresh the time-out successfully.

Comment: But when does it timeout? Does it timeout on getting the list? Or in getting one of the files?

Comment: It times-out getting the files after 60secs. We've tried so many things and nothing is working. This link http://www.devthought.com/2012/09/22/understanding-the-ios6-ajax-bugs/ talks about iOS6 & AJAX issues. Have you heard of anything like this that could be causing our particular issue?

Comment: Odd, I am doing a very similar thing and I don't get any timeout errors - I am able to download >200MB of content sometimes taking >5 minutes and never get the error

Comment: I guess what I might be doing differently is getting the list of assets via a JSON feed, then storing the feed.  Then linking to and downloading each file from the saved feed.

Comment: **UPDATED SOLUTION:** we have fixed the problem. The issue fundamentally lies in the fact that iOS Safari times out at _**60secs**_. Why? We have no idea... What we were doing was fetching the full list files to download, and then downloading them synchronously. What happened at 60secs, is the download times out and we were losing our file list. What we did to resolve this, is we saved the "files not downloaded list" at 60secs, and then started the download process again with this new list, and repeated this process until all files successfully downloaded.

Comment: Waw, i just hit a similar thing.. And I could not understand why this happen.. So will the transfer fail ? or do I need to check for the file on Success as well to implement retry?

Comment: Yes, check which files have failed and then retry that file list again, and repeat the process until all files have downloaded.