# phonegap/iOS external images intermittently not loading/showing

Tags: html, ios, image, cordova

OK so this issue is driving me insane. I am building a messaging app which contains lots of user profiles and profile images. On message threads, each user message contains their profile image so in some case there will be lots of images rendered to the page.

Once the app is run for the first time and I browse through different message threads all images appear fine but then after a while new images simply stop rendering. Weirdly enough, if I put the phone to sleep by clicking the top right power button and then unlock the phone and revisit the app the images appear. The images will also sometimes randomly appear after a period of time.

Has anyone had any similar issues like this? I can only imagine it has something to do with the devices memory and image handling. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: Hi there

I seem to be having the same intermittent loading of images issue (very annoying). The problem occurs both with images loaded from an external website, as well as for Google Maps image tiles, and I can't see why. 

To try to narrow it down, are you by any chance:
1) Using AngularJS?
2) Storing URLs to images in JSON?

I am using both, and wondering if it has anything to do with either.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when developing an app with Cordova/PhoneGap. This problem is just a version issue, i.e, if you update Cordova or PhoneGap in your machine, you must do the same with plugins already added to the project.

In this case, the problem was related to [whitelist](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html) plugin. You don't need to add specific origins, because Cordova already did this when creating the project, allowing all the URLs:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

The solution: 
First remove the plugin:

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

And then, add it again:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues, but it seems my issue was due to upgrading from PhoneGap 2.9 to 3.1 and the config.xml URL whitelist syntax having changed (and thus blocking images) as documented here http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html, and I may have been swapping back and forth between PhoneGap versions which is why it appeared intermittent (or perhaps the images were cached initially and then subsequently not loaded).

Some other links that may help solve your problem:

https://github.com/phonegap/build/issues/16

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/guide_project-settings_android_index.md.html#Project%20Settings%20for%20Android (loadUrlTimeoutValue setting)

[iOS / PhoneGap app fails to download remote images/video via REST API after 60secs - why is it timing out?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18386271/1371408)

Or maybe you are exceeding the file download size limit, and that is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

i honestly would suggest trying to find a different compiler other than phonegap i have heard people have many problems with media file like images and video as i think its plugin has trouble rendering the data i have made an app in the past for android and experienced the same problem with trying to add mp4 files to it

Comment: this isn't the reply I was hoping for! thanks but surely there must be some resolution. Do you know what the root of the cause could be?

Comment: sorry i dont its only from things i have heard and experienced myself would need to check with adobe

Answer (score 0):

As Matty J said, this could be related to [domain whitelisting](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html).

A common issue is that an API will be on the whitelist, and so all the requests and resources from that URL will work, but it may link to images stored on a CDN such as Amazon AWS.

So, check the URLs of the images which aren't loading by using [Safari's Remote Device inspector](http://moduscreate.com/enable-remote-web-inspector-in-ios-6/), then in your config.xml file put the following.

```
<access origin="*.your-api-domain-here.com*" />
<access origin="*.your-cdn-domain-here.com*" />
```

Then give it a go.

Keep in mind that **there is a version of PhoneGap/Cordova which only allows a single whitelisted domain** and I *think* it's version 3.2, so get up-to-date if you can.